# Type '{ key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Product' Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am having this problem "Type '{ key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Product'." when I add to an array products variable the Product interface type.

Here is my code:

**product.ts**

```
export interface Product {
    title: string;
    price: number;
    category: string;
    imageUrl: string;
}
```

**productService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  create(product){
    return this.db.list('/products').push(product);
  }

  getAll(){
    return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions =>
          actions.map(a => ({ key: a.key, ...a.payload.val() }))
        )
      );
  }

  get(productId){
    return this.db.object('/products/' + productId).valueChanges();
  }

  update(productId, product){
    return this.db.object('/products/' + productId).update(product);
  }

  delete(productId){
    return this.db.object('/products/' + productId).remove();
  }
}
```

**admin-product.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/product.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-products',
  templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.css']
})
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  products: Product[];
  filteredProducts: any[];
  subscription: Subscription;
  dataSource;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['title', 'price', 'action'];

  constructor(private productService: ProductService){
    this.subscription = this.productService.getAll().subscribe(products => this.filteredProducts = this.products = products);
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  filter(query: string){
    if(query){
      this.filteredProducts = this.products.filter(p => p.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()));
    }else{
      this.filteredProducts = this.products;
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**terminal error**

```
ERROR in src/app/admin/admin-products/admin-products.component.ts(19,100): error TS2322: Type '{ key: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.
```

src/app/admin/admin-products/admin-products.component.ts(19,100): error TS2322: Type '{ key: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.
  Type '{ key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
    Property 'title' is missing in type '{ key: string; }'.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: what types are in observable returned from `this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for an suggestion,

It seems something you have mapped and assigned value to a mentioned name(key).

```
getAll(){
    return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions =>
          actions.map(a => ({ key: a.key, ...a.payload.val() })) //here you have made something strange.
        )
      );
  }
```

Solution:-
  You need map proper interface model variable.

```
example,
  .map( {title: a.something;
    price: a.something;
    category: a.something;
    imageUrl: a.something
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay @Karnan Muthukumar. I got it working using this code with your help:
getAll(){
    return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions =>
          actions.map(a => ({ key: a.key, ...a.payload.val() } as Product))
        )
      );
  }

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for replay to all.

I got it working using this code with your help Karnan Muthukumar:

```
getAll(){
    return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions =>
          actions.map(a => ({ key: a.key, ...a.payload.val() } as Product))
        )
      );
  }
```

Comment: `key` still is not available on the product interface if you wanted to use it later. You could just add it to the interface which would allow other places to use that property. That way, you won't have to cast the type to Product, it'll just work.

Comment: Right on add key to the interface still need that "as Product" to save the day clean and simple!

Answer (score 0):

You could console.log the observable returned in `this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges()` and see what params are on it, probably there are more thing that only a Product so you will have to choose what you want from this Observable.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that, you are trying to use a generic object returned from your service as a typed Object.  I like to use `.map` and `Object.assign()` to covert things, like this:

```
  getAll(){
    return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions =>
          actions.map(a => (Object.assign(new ClassThatImplementsProductInferface(), a))
        )
      );
  }
```

This assumes that the data returned from `snapshotChanges()` has all the data and could be a Product Interface.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution would be , if you definitely know the response type.

```
(actions as unknown)as Product
```